# Gulp and Protractor - prevent rerun if test code has syntax issues

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm using gulp and protractor to test my angular app.

I have a task that auto run the test on every change:

```
gulp.task('watch-protractor', function () {
    gulp_config.watchtest = true;
    gulp.watch(['public/master/tests/**/*.js'], ['protractor']);
});
```

and a task that run the test:

```
gulp.task('protractor', ['webdriver:update'], function () {
    return gulp.src(gulp_config.source.test.e2e)
        .pipe(protractor({
            configFile: 'protractor.conf.js'
        }))
        .on('error', function (e) {
            throw e
        });
});
```

My problem is that if I'm saving a test spec in the middle of typing, the gulp rerun the tests, crash due to syntax error and the entire gulp task and server crashes.

Can I configure protractor to run only if the spec compiles? any alternative to my design?

Comment: What if you configure your IDE to save the file if only you ask about it?..

Comment: You should probably configure jshint to run before protractor. Make it a dependency of your test task, and then it will be required to complete successfully before the tests.

Comment: Care to share a code sample? @juunas